# How to log usage of built-in functions in PHP?

Tags: php, logging, nginx, fpm

Consider a built in php function, for example `file_put_contents()`. Running php-fpm on Nginx is it possible to log all usages of that function?

The example output i'm thinking about is something like this:

```
timestamp path_to_the_file_which_used_the_function  parameters_passed_to_the_function
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable [profiling in Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). This logs many times each function is called, execution time and call stack. It may not show parameters passed, however.